# Where are files generated by webpack using angular-cli

Tags: angular, webpack-dev-server, angular-cli

I'm using `angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.19-3` and when I run `ng serve` I get the following output:

```
           Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
  main.bundle.js    2.71 MB    0, 2  [emitted]  main
styles.bundle.js    10.2 kB    1, 2  [emitted]  styles
       inline.js    5.53 kB       2  [emitted]  inline
        main.map    2.81 MB    0, 2  [emitted]  main
      styles.map    14.1 kB    1, 2  [emitted]  styles
      inline.map    5.59 kB       2  [emitted]  inline
      index.html  486 bytes          [emitted]
```

and I can access the app using `http://localhost:4200/`. However, I can't find those files inside my app. Are those bundles not ouput and kept in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webpack dev server compiles and hosts the files via memory so they are not written to disk, which explains why you can not find them.

Comment: yeah, that's what I thought. Is there any way to configure `angular-cli` to ouput built files?

Comment: You can run `ng build --watch` and then use a different web server such as `live-server` but I don't know if webpack-dev-server has that option or if the CLI exposes it (I don't think so)